# jQuery Ajax pull data from a Form request on another page?

Tags: ajax, forms, jquery

I want to grab some elements of a page using jQuery and ajax...no problem.  However, the elements do not appear until a user clicks a button in the form, so essentially I cannot pull anything off the page unless that is executed.  Anyone know how this can be achieved?  I will post samples and what I am trying to accomplish.

I want to pull data from all orders 12 months previous (value=12).  This is the form that is given on the page:

```
<form action="" method="post" name="form2">       
  <table>
    <tbody><tr> 
      <td align="center"><span><b>Order History</b></span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr> 
      <td> 
        <table>
          <tbody><tr>      
            <td width="235"> 
<select name="date">
<option selected="" value="1">Orders placed in the past 1 month</option>
<option value="3">Orders placed in the past 3 months</option>
<option value="6">Orders placed in the past 6 months</option>
<option value="12">Orders placed in the past 12 months</option>
<option value="2011"> Orders placed in 2011</option>
<option value="2010"> Orders placed in 2010</option>
<option value="2009"> Orders placed in 2009</option>
</select>
            </td> 
            <td width="43"> 
          <input type="image" border="0" src="v/vspfiles/templates/4/images/Template/btn_go.gif" name="imageField">
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody></table>  
  <br>
</form>
```

Once the data is displayed, the url does not change so it is still '/orders.asp', but I want to then grab that data using ajax.  Is this possible?

Right now one has to go to their **My Account** page, then they have to click a link which takes them to their **Orders** page where this form is located.  I want to automatically display thier most recent orders on their **My Account** page.

Comment: What do you mean pull the data? Where is the data stored? Where do you want to put it?

Comment: I'm not sure where the data is stored thats why I am trying to pull it.  My shopping cart does not allow me to edit the .asp pages so I cannot edit any part of the form.  When one clicks the Form, selects the option and clicks a Go button it spits out their order information.  I'm trying to take that order information and put it on their /myaccount.asp page, (basically moving the data so like a quick view of their recent orders).

Comment: well... then I guess you need to submit the form to myaccount.asp

Comment: Good idea Alex, i will attempt to re-create the form on another page to see if it will pull the same data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not clear where you're stuck.

One can wire some JavaScript that will execute when the user selects any of the options (eg.12)

The Javascript can initiate an Ajax call - this retrieves some data

The ajax call hits a service on the server that gathers some data , which should be just data, not HTML

When the Ajax call completes some more javascript can look at the response, and manipulate the DOM in the browser to present the data.

From your question I can't figure out where you need the help.

Comment: Ok.  There is no problem with the form itself.  It spits out data no problem.  I want to take that data it spits out and put it on another page...using ajax written on another page.

Comment: I have modified my question and added a paragraph at the end for more clarification.